# Showing flows converge in the phase plane

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I have a system of ODEs:

$$\dot{x} = \frac{m_1 x (1-x-y)}{a_1 + 1-x-y} - x$$
$$\dot{y} = \frac{m_2 y (1-x-y)}{a_2 + 1-x-y} - y$$

I'm trying to show that all the flows converge to the point $(1-\lambda_1,0)$ but I'm having some difficulties. (Here $\lambda_{1,2} = \frac{a_{1,2}}{m_{1,2}-1}$, $0 < \lambda < 1$ and $m>1$)

I can see that on the line $x+y = 1$ the flow is pointing "inwards" and along the axis $x=0$ $y=0$ the flow is along those axes and so the particle will stay in the upper right quadrant region bounded by those lines.

I can also see there is a critical point at (0,0) which I think gives an unstable node.

I've also found critical point at $(0,1-\lambda_2)$ and $(1-\lambda_1,0)$ but I can't figure out how to analyse these.

I'm struggling to put this together to get the convergence claim.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Where the flow goes depends on the specific values of $a,m$. If $m=0$ for example then $(x,y)=(x_0e^{-t},y_0e^{-t}) \to (0,0)$ so "all the flows converge to the point $(1-\lambda,0)$" is not always correct.

Comment: It can be useful to define $z=x+y$ when studying the system. By adding the two ODE's we obtain a single ODE just for $z$: $\dot{z} = \frac{mz(1-z)}{a+1-z} - z$

Comment: Okay thank you for the suggestion, I will try that out and see if I make any progress. I've also made an edit with the conditions on $\lambda$ and $m$ which I forgot to mention originally

Comment: Good. With the conditions you have now then $0 < m - 1 - a$ and by linearizing around $z = 0$ we find that this is an unstable fixpoint.

Comment: Okay I see, how do we deal with the stability/classifying the other two fixed points?

Comment: I wrote down a short note below giving a general procedure to check stability for any fixpoint.

Answer (score 1):

To check fixpoint stability we linearize the equations around the fixpoint $(x,y) = (\overline{x} ,\overline{y})$. Put $x= \overline{x} + \delta x$, $y= \overline{y} + \delta y$ and expand the equations to first order in the perturbations. For a general system

$$\dot{x} = F(x,y)$$
$$\dot{y} = G(x,y)$$

the fixpoints are determined by $F(\overline{x},\overline{y})=G(\overline{x},\overline{y})=0$. Linearizing around such a point gives us the perturbations equations

$$\dot{\delta x} = \left.\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x}\right|_{(x,y)=(\overline{x} ,\overline{y})}\delta x + \left.\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial y}\right|_{(x,y)=(\overline{x} ,\overline{y})}\delta y$$

$$\dot{\delta y} = \left.\frac{\partial G(x,y)}{\partial x}\right|_{(x,y)=(\overline{x} ,\overline{y})}\delta x + \left.\frac{\partial G(x,y)}{\partial y}\right|_{(x,y)=(\overline{x} ,\overline{y})}\delta y$$

Now try to solve this system and see if it has exponentially growing or decaying solutions. Exponentially decaying solutions indicates stability while exponentially increasing solutions indicates that the fixpoint is unstable.

---

As an example: For your problem (for simplicity taking $m_1=m_2=m$ and $a_1=a_2=a$) and the fixpoint $(x,y) = (0,1-\lambda)$ we find

$$\dot{\delta x} = -\frac{1}{m+1}\delta x$$

$$\dot{\delta y} = \frac{(a-m)m^2}{a(1+m)^2}\delta x - \frac{m^3 + a(1+m-m^2)}{a(1+m)^2}\delta y$$

The first equation has the solution $\delta x(t) = \delta x(0) e^{-\frac{t}{m+1}}$ and is exponentially decaying. The second equation has the solution

$$\delta y = \delta x(0)  e^{-\frac{t}{(1+m)}} + (\delta y(0) - \delta x(0))e^{-\frac{m^3 + a(1+m-m^2)}{a(1+m)^2}t}$$

which is also exponentially decaying since $m^3 + a(1+m-m^2)  = m^2(m-a) + a(1+m) > 0$ since $a+1<m$. This shows that the fixpoint $(0,1-\lambda)$ is a stable fixpoint.

Comment: How does it answer the question?

Comment: @Artem Have you read the question and the comments below it? OP is unsure how to solve parts of the problem. I just give the general method to a question he had. I'm not going to present a full worked out solution to what is most likely a homework problem.

Comment: Do you really think that I posted my answer before reading the question? -1, which I would gladly change for +1 if you do present a full worked out solution.

Comment: @Artem If you read all the comments then you'll see that this is just a note for OP, not an answer to the whole question. Whatever you feel like, I couldn't care less about the points here.

Comment: I find the hint more helpful for my understanding than a full written answer. I'm just wondering how you obtained the equation for $\delta \dot{x}$? I get $\delta \dot{x} = (\frac{m_1 \lambda_2}{a_1 + \lambda_2}-1) \delta x$? This is harder to interpret

Comment: In fact I think this implies it is an unstable fixed point (at least in the x direction)

Comment: @Wooster In your post you have $m_1$ and $a_1$ in both equations. I have assumed this (and $m = m_1$, $a=a_1$ in my note). Reading it now it seems like you perhaps mean it to be $a_1,m_1$ in the first and $a_2,m_2$ in the second equation? If so then my results above are wrong.

Comment: From your solution: If we put $C = \frac{m_1\lambda_2}{a_1 + \lambda_2} - 1$ then the solution is $\delta x \propto e^{Ct}$ so the solution is stable for $C<0$, i.e.  $\frac{m_1\lambda_2}{a_1 + \lambda_2} < 1$

Comment: Yes that what I was thinking, however it then seems difficult to say that the flows converge to $(1-\lambda_1,0)$

Comment: And yes I made an error in the constants which I've now corrected!

Comment: I think I've managed to find that the point on the x axis is stable and the y axis point is unstable. Sketching the flows on the lines $x+y = 1-\lambda_i$ then implies all the flows converge to the desired point!

Comment: @Wooster Very good. Glad that you finished it. I checked and I also get the same value for what I called '$C$' above for the $(0,1-\lambda_2)$ fixpoint. btw if you want you can write up an answer to your own question and post it.